# How to set Countdown time format

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable, countdowntimer

I was use `runnable()` to make countdown timer on my game

i was set `int cd=30;`

and this is the method for run it

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable mUpdateTimeTasks = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        countdowntext.setText(String.valueOf(cd));
        cd -=1;
        if(cd < 10) {
            countdowntext.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        if(cd == 0) {
           focus.stop();                                      
        }
    };
    // run this in a method.
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTasks, cd);
}
```

the code was work fine but the problem just the coundown timer run so fast, i just wonder how to make int cd=1 = 1 second too, so cd=30 = 30 second

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i just wonder how to make int cd=1 = 1 second too, so cd=30 = 30
>   second

then you should use `mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTasks, 1000)`

```
final Runnable mUpdateTimeTasks = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
           countdowntext.setText(String.valueOf(cd));
           cd -=1;
           if(cd < 10) {
                countdowntext.setTextColor(Color.RED);
           }
           if(cd == 0) { 
                focus.stop();        
                mHandler.removaCallbacks(null);
                return;                   
           }
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
};
```

this will not give exactly 30 seconds but something really close to it

Answer (score 0):

> In **mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTasks, cd);** cd is millisecond

You should change your code from:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

final Runnable mUpdateTimeTasks = new Runnable() {

```
public void run() {
    countdowntext.setText(String.valueOf(cd));
    cd -=1;
    if(cd < 10) {
        countdowntext.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    if(cd == 0) {
       focus.stop();                                      
    }
};
// run this in a method.
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTasks, cd);
 }
```

To this:

```
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable mUpdateTimeTasks = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        countdowntext.setText(String.valueOf(cd));
        cd -=1;
        if(cd < 10) {
            countdowntext.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        if(cd == 0) {
           focus.stop();    
           mHandler.removaCallbacks(null);  
           return();                                
        }
    };
    // run this in a method.
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTasks, 1000);
    }
```

**1000** means that after one second(1000/1000 sec) check the **Runnable mUpdateTimeTasks** method.